# Get the Content comes under 'text' with Java Pattern

Tags: java, regex

I need to capture all the String content comes under `' '`. Through pattern.

```
String mydata2 = "some string with 'the data i want1' inside  'the data i want2'";

Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile("'(.*?)'");

Matcher matcher2 = pattern2.matcher(mydata2);

if (matcher2.find()) 
  System.out.println(matcher2.group(1));
```

How do I get the output using Java pattern , Regular Expression API

the data i want1

the data i want2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Matching Without the Quotes: Capture Group**

To iterate through the strings, use this:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("'([^']+)'");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    // do something with the match, which is regexMatcher.group(1)
}
```

On [the regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/gY7rO4/23), see the capture group in the right pane (the quotes are not included).

**Explanation**

- The regex is `'([^']+)'`
- `'` matches the opening quote
- `([^']+)` captures the inside of the quotes to Group 1: one or more chars that are not a quote
- `'` matches the closing quote
- We retrieve the matches from Group 1

Comment: FYI: Added demo and explanation :)

Comment: How to retrieve the text comes under regular expression. I can get the count. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression is **correct** here.

The issue is an `if` statement executes a certain section of code only if a particular condition is true. Using a `while` statement will continually execute a block of statements while a particular condition is true.

You should use a while loop to loop over your matches.

```
while (matcher2.find()) {
  System.out.println(matcher2.group(1));
}
```

[Working Demo](http://ideone.com/y7r7hJ)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class RegEx
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String mydata2 = "some string with 'the data i want1' inside 'the data i want2'";
        Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile("'(.*?)'");

        Matcher matcher2 = pattern2.matcher(mydata2);

        while (matcher2.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher2.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```